# Why can't I make Killer Bunny spawners and Ender Dragon spawners?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have tried Youtube videos, tutorials, Minecraft wiki, and many different types of commands. If I tried: `/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:RabbitType:99}`or `/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:KillerRabbit}` it will just give me an empty spawner with nothing in it. The same goes for the Ender Dragon commands. Can anyone give me an explanation please?

Answer (score 3):

Extra entity data goes inside the `SpawnData` compound. The correct tag name is `RabbitType` rather than `Type`. Tags are separated with commas.

Fixed command for 1.8:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {EntityId:Rabbit,SpawnData:{RabbitType:99}}
```

Fixed command for 1.9, where `EntityId` no longer exists and the ID is instead defined by the `id` tag inside of `SpawnData`:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnData:{id:Rabbit,RabbitType:99}}
```